# Why does $9x(x − 1) = 9x − 5$ imply $9x^2 − 18x + 5 = 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Define
$$f(x) = 9x(x - 1) \quad\text{and}\quad g(x) = 9x - 5$$
We have 
$$
\begin {align}
f(x)=g(x)&\implies 9x(x − 1) = 9x − 5 \\
&\implies 9x^2 − 18x + 5 = 0 \\
&\implies (3x)^2 − 6(3x) + 5 = 0 \\
&\implies (3x − 1)(3x − 5) = 0
\end{align}
$$

Can someone tell me here, why the $9x(x - 1) = 9x - 5$
leads to $9x^2 - 18x + 5 = 0$?

Answer (score 6):

From $$9x(x-1)=9x-5$$ applying distributivity of the multiplication with respect to the addition we get $$9x^2-9x=9x-5$$

Adding $-9x+5$ on both sides we get $$9x^2-9x-9x+5=0$$
Associating terms $$9x^2-18x+5=0$$

Comment: I think it might be slightly confusing to use terms such as "distributivity" to someone with this level of algebraic knowledge, without explaining them. But if the OP is still confused: https://www.dummies.com/education/math/algebra/how-to-perform-distribution-in-algebra/